# MySQLMembershipProvider and MySQLRoleProvider not showing in ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have MySQL running with the ASP Membership Schema

I have installed the connector, and have the following in machine.config:

```
<add 
  name="MySQL Data Provider" 
  invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
  description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, 
    MySql.Data, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=****" />
```

and

```
<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" 
  autogenerateschema="true"  
  type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, 
    MySql.Web, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****" 
  connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
  enablePasswordReset="true" 
  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
  applicationName="/" 
  requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
  passwordFormat="Clear" 
  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
  minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
  passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
  passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

I also have in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
<add name="LocalMySqlServer"
  connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=******;uid=****;pwd=***;"
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However, when I go to the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool, I only see the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and not the MySQLMembershipProvider :

How can I get the MySQL provider to appear in this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I just added the config sections directly to the web.config for the application, rather than in machine.config and the app picked it up fine.

Comment: Love when I come across a former colleagues solution :) Cheers mate!